# Advanced custom fields upload image into select box (conceptual)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a wordpress site using advanced custom fields pro with the repeater fields enabled.

Can anyone think of a way to integrate

1. A repeater field for uploading images with
2. A repeater field select dropdown

Such that on the back-end the client can either

1. Select an image to go with a menu item from a dropdown of pre-existing images; or
2. Upload an image to go with the menu item **that will then be available in the dropdown for future uses**

The page currently in development is viewable at http://elmeson.dukecitydigital.com/?page_id=1732
Where you can see how the flags go with the menu items.

The code i'm using for the dropdown select is

```
<?php if ( have_rows('menu_items') ):
    while ( have_rows('menu_items') ): the_row(); ?>
<div><?php the_sub_field("menu_item_name");?></div>
<div><?php the_sub_field("menu_item_price");?></div>
<div><?php the_sub_field("menu_item_description");?></div>
<?php
$flagname = get_sub_field('menu_item_flag');
if ($flagname === "andalucia") {
     $image_url = "img/andalucia.png";
    } elseif ($flagname === "asturias") {
        $image_url = "img/asturias.png";
    } elseif ($flagname === "aragon") {
        $image_url = "img/aragon.png";
<div><?php the_sub_field($image_url);?></div>
```

Thanks a lot for your consideration

Comment: Have you looked at using an ACF image field, and just using the WordPress media system to handle the upload? That way a user could select a flag that's already uploaded, or upload a new one. Do you need other data to be associated with the image, like the name of the country? If that's the case, you may be better off setting up a custom post type called 'flags' and using some custom fields on that, then having your ACF dropdown select from the 'flags' posts. You could then pull in any associated meta-data from those as needed.